# Zariski tangent space of a point viewed as a point of a subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be an affine variety (not irreducible). Let $Y$ be a subvariety of $X$ (again not irreducible). How can we relate the Zariski tangent space at $P \in Y$ and at $P \in X$?

(Corrected after Mariano's comments)
Based on my understanding, we do have a homomorphism $T_P Y \rightarrow T_P X$ of vector spaces, but can we say something more? For example, what can we say about the dimensions of the two vector spaces $T_PY$ and $T_PX$?

Comment: Do you mean "not irreducible" or "not necessarily irreducible"?

Comment: @NilsMatthes: Yes, i mean "not necessarily irreducible" :)

Comment: What homomorphism $T_pX\to T_pY$ do you have in mind? Notice that there are tons of such homomorphisms, simply because we could take the zero map, say, but presumably you have in mind a natural one.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Yes you are right, i mean the canonical one.

Comment: and *what* is the canonical one?!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: It is the one induced by the canonical map between cotangent spaces $m_{P,X}/m^2_{P,X} \rightarrow m_{P,Y}/m^2_{P,Y}$. I am not sure though how it looks like :)

Comment: You are saying that that map induces a map $T_pX\to T_pY$? How?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Since $\left(m_{P,X}/m^2_{P,X}\right)^* \cong T_PX$ by definition, where $*$ means dual, and each vector space of finite dimension is isomorphic to its dual, then we get a morphism $T_PX \rightarrow T_PY$. Right?

Comment: No, you do not get a morphism from $T_pX$ to $T_pY$ that way (and that the dual of a fin.dim. vector space is isomorphic to the vector space itself probably has nothing to do with what you want to say)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Haha, ok, so...what should i say then? Is there another canonical or natural map between the tangent spaces?

Comment: Can you see *why* you do not get a map from $T_pX$ to $T_pY$ from your map $m_{p,X}/m_{p,X}^2\to m_{p,Y}/m_{p,Y}^2$ by taking duals? *what* do you get?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: No i can not see that, since if $f: m_{P,X}/m^2_{P,X} \rightarrow m_{P,Y}/m^2_{P,Y}$ is the canonical map of the cotangent spaces and we call $\psi_X : m_{P,X}/m^2_{P,X} \rightarrow T_PX$ the isomorphism between cotangent and tangent spaces, and similarly$\psi_Y : m_{P,Y}/m^2_{P,Y} \rightarrow T_PY$, then we certainly get a morphism $T_PX \rightarrow T_PY$ by $\psi_Y \circ f \circ \psi_X^{-1}$. Right?

Comment: Anything that involves an isomorphism between a vector space and its dual is wrong.

Comment: If $f:V\to W$ is a linear map between vector spaces, **what** do you get by taking dual vector spaces?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Ahh, i see, the order gets reversed...I will get $f^* : W^* \rightarrow V^*$.

Comment: There you go. ${}$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Thank you so much for teaching me!!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: But could please explain the statement "anything that involves isomorphism between a vector space and its dual is wrong"? We know that if a vector space is finite dimensional, then it is isomorphic to its dual...

Comment: Dear @Manos, But the isomorphism is, in general, non-canonical, as it involves the choice of a basis. So if you're looking for a canonical map, choosing an isomorphism between a finite dimensional vector space and its dual is probably not going to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural $\Bbb{C}$-linear map 
$$
T_P(Y) \rightarrow T_P(X)
$$ is indeed injective. This follows from the fact that it is dual to the $\Bbb{C}$-linear map
$$
\mathfrak{m}_{X,P}/\mathfrak{m}_{X,P}^2 \rightarrow \mathfrak{m}_{Y,P}/\mathfrak{m}_{Y,P}^2
$$
which is surjective, since $Y$ is a subvariety of $X$. Hence one always has

$$
\dim T_P(Y) \leq \dim T_P(X)
$$

and this result cannot be improved; you can have strict inequality (e.g. $X=\Bbb{A}^1$, $Y=P$ for some point $P \in \Bbb{A}^1$) and you can have equality (e.g. $X=\Bbb{A}^2$, $Y=V(y^2-x^3)$ and $P=(0,0)$).

Comment: One more question please, to make sure i understand correctly the definitions: if all the gradients of the generators of the vanishing ideal of an affine variety $X$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ are zero at a certain point $P$, then this means that the Zariski tangent space at this point is the entire $\mathbb{C}^n$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, Manos.